# Request.form doesn't return a value with Visual Studio 2013 in code behind

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-behind, textinput, asp.net-4.5

I think I'm getting blind....! What's wrong with the following code? 
With Visual Studio 2013 "searchBox" doesn't return a value but with VS 2008 it works well.

CODE BEHIND

```
Partial Class _Default
Inherits Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
           Response.Write(Request.Form("searchBox"))
End Sub
```

End Class

HTML PAGE

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %> 
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't works with VS2008 either. As it is a server control, the actual client id of the control won't be `searchbox` but a concatenation of all parents ids of the control. Something like `ctl00_somePanel_someContainer_SearchBox`.

`Request.Form` will contain raw html form control's values, including the value generated by the client side version of the `SearchBox`, with its actual generated id.

To solve your issue, you can:

- read the `SearchBox.Text` property instead of reading the `Form` object (probably the best option)
- replace the server control by a pure client one (`<input type='textbox' id='SearchBox'/>`
- fix the control ID using `CliendIDMode`, but I believe this is a poor option

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. This is exactly the philosophy of ASP.Net and server control. This mimics a windows app development allowing the developer to read/write control properties. The asp.net engine (and specifically the viewstate management), will handle all the magic of rebuilding the controls.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be when you want to use Request.Form("searchBox") is to set it as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" clientmode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

This forces the object to be created with the name "***SearchBox***" that you set it too, not "**ctl00_somePanel_someContainer_SearchBox**" that is a name that only it knows how to interpret.

It is not the best way to access the object, but this will get you going the way you are doing it.